# What is the relation between .net web forms, windows forms project and the IIS Forms authentication?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, model-view-controller, forms-authentication

I am working on a .NET 6 ASP.NET website and looking at implementing authentication using the identity framework. I understand this is technically working as a middleware and is independent of the subsequent IIS deployment authentication setting (only anonymous needs enabling).

On the IIS authentication setting I can various authentication options, one of which is called Forms Authentication.

1. I want to ask whether there is any relation between .NET Web Forms (or Windows Forms) project and the IIS Forms authentication? Or is it just a co-incidence that they both have the Forms keyword? I am confused because - like Web Forms project, even older ASP.NET MVC project required the Form Authentication enabled upon deployment to IIS. Where as newer .NET MVC project don't require this IIS deployment setting if they are using the Identity framework.
2. The latest authentication mechanism is called Identity framework. What was the older authentication mechanism technically called? Forms auth framework?

Answer (score 0):

> want to ask whether there is any relation between .NET Web Forms (or Windows Forms) project and the IIS Forms authentication?

Don't bring windows forms into this!!

But, yes, so called FBA (forms based aunthetiicaion) is not really realited to web forms in any speical way. They just happen to both have the name "forms" in their name - nothing more, and nothing less. So, using FBA in web forms applciations was a long time common choice.

Is there a relationship bettween FBA and IIS? yes, because if you adopt FBA, then your web site security is managed using that security provider. This useally means you have the "role" provider and FBA provider.

so, then each folder of the web site can then be secuired using web.config. You can either secuire those pages to require a valid logon (based on FBA), and you can also pick and choose what roles (so, some parts of the site say can only be used with say a role of "Sales" group.

However, while the web forms site can adopt FBA, the valuable informtion is that IIS will respect that that authneticaion provider - and thus IIS "knows" and "respects" that secuirty provider choice. That means say if you hit a web page that requires  logon, then IIS will automatic intercept that page - send you to the logon page, and after you logon, you can continue on to that secured web page.

However, you don't have to use FBA with IIS, there are of course other secuirty and logon providers you can use. However, you do want to use a supported and started one, since then you can use the built-in asp.net logon controls etc, and they will just work.

> What was the older authentication mechanism technically called?

FBA -- Forms based authentication. As I stated, the fact of "forms" in that name FBA has no specials meaning in regards to web forms, or using web form applications.
You are thus as noted are free to adopt newer security providers - web forms are of course not limited to using FBA as the security provider.

> even older ASP.NET MVC project required the Form Authentication enabled upon deployment to IIS.

Hum, did they? I don't think that is the case. If you don't want or need web site logons or security then I do not believe that FBA was any kind of requirement to be enabled at all to deploy a web site that does not have nor use security.

Comment: `Is there a relationship bettween FBA and IIS? yes` - does this also mean that IIS is the only web server that supports a website using FBA? Or does other server like nginx also support FBA?

Comment: `so, then each folder of the web site can then be secuired using web.config.` - is web.config in each folder concept applicable only to IIS or does this work the same was for other web servers like nginx?

Comment: `Hum, did they? I don't think that is the case. If you don't want or need web site logons or security then I do not believe that FBA was any kind of requirement to be enabled at all to deploy a web site that does not have nor use security.` - I meant assuming the MVC site required authentication functionality

Comment: @variable you must be surprised to know that ASP.NET 4.x on Mono supports FBA without IIS. FBA is totally an ASP.NET concept, so has nothing to do with IIS or any other web server like nginx.

Comment: @variable `web.config` stores both IIS and ASP.NET settings but under separate tag systems. No other web server (nginx for instance) ever support `web.config`. If you simply read the configuration references of such web servers, the answer is more than obvious.

Comment: @variable ASP.NET (WebForms or MVC) can live happily without FBA, so I wonder from where you learned that FBA is "required".

Comment: "Is there a relationship bettween FBA and IIS? yes, because ..." is completely wrong. See my previous comment please. "the valuable informtion is that IIS will respect that that authneticaion provider - and thus IIS "knows" and "respects" that secuirty provider choice" is also incorrect.

Comment: So when you secure a folder with web config based on FBA, their's no code needed or changes in web site code - it's IIS doing that security, right?